# why is dispatch() is adding additional property 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-toolkit

I am manipulating an obj, so that it can be dispatched using redux, by using foll code.

```
const objMap = {};
const propList = ['apple', 'banana'];

for (const prop of propList) {
   objMap[prop] = 0;
}
console.log("thunk2: ", materialMap);
dispatch(reduxActions.updateCount({ objMap }));
```

**without** `dispatch();` line of code, result is

```
{
  "apple": 0,
  "banana": 0,
}
```

but **when dispatch() is used** then result is as below with extra property 'undefined'

```
{
    "apple": 0,
    "banana": 0,
    "undefined": null
}
```

why is 'undefined' being added?

Comment: What does `updateCount` do?

Comment: What does the reducer do?

Comment: updateCount(state, action) {
      state.ObjMap= action.payload.ObjMap;
      const fruitType= action.payload.ObjMap;
      const userAction = action.payload.userAction;

      if (userAction === "add") {
        state.ObjMap[fruitType] += 1;
      } else {
        state.ObjMap[fruitType] -= 1;
      }
    }

reducer receives dispatch and updates the count of the each fruit in the ObjMap.

Comment: What is `materialMap`? The reducer is modifying the existing state and not returning anything? What do you mean by "result" when you say it has the extra property? Where are you getting that? There's not enough information here to answer your question.

Comment: sorry, I edited it, I am dispatching from two places and using one reducer. I guess i have a  logical error. I realized with your questions. I will re-visit code. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I revisited my code and it's a logical error. Not an issue with dispatch() api itself.